# React App and Express Server routing for a single page application

Tags: reactjs, express

How do I set the routes for my React Single page application in Express js
Navigate a React App link from a single page application to Express server dynamically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845466/13769976 Is it this what you looking for

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear but I'm assuming you want to know how to use express for API routes and still server react on the frontend. If this is the case you can do it like this on your backend file (let's call it server.js). And the react app is in a folder called "client":

```
const app = express();

// API routes
app.get("/api/test", (req, res) => {
  res.send('example response from backend');
});


// If no API routes are hit, send the React app
app.use(function (req: Request, res: Response) {
res.sendFile(join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
});
```

Note that you have to send the React app last. This line **must** come after all other routes.